# How to check if all instances of a React Component have the same value for their state?

Tags: reactjs, jsx

So right now, in my App file I have this:

```
{items.map(el => (
                    <Item
                        prop1={foo}
                        prop2={bar}
                        el={baz}
                    />
                ))}
```

And in the `<Item>` component, I have this:

```
            <span className={finishedClass ? "finishedItem" : ""}>
                {props.el}
            </span>
```

where `finishedClass` is a state variable.

So my question is, how can I check if `finishedClass` is true for every single `<Item>` component that gets generated as a result of the `items.map`?

Answer (score 0):

So, you basically want to know if all the `finishedClass` state values in all the `Item` components are true. This can be simplified in the sense that if any of the Item components have `finishedClass` as false, you will perform a certain action.

So, what you can do is, pass a function as a prop to the `Item` component as follows:

```
{items.map(el => (
                    <Item
                        prop1={foo}
                        prop2={bar}
                        el={baz}
                        setFinishedClassToFalse={()=>{/*your statements*/}}
                    />
                ))}
```

This function `setFinishedClassToFalse` will be called by the `Item` component if and only if its state value `finishedClass` is false. Obviously, there's a little more implementation to this than what I have described. But this should give you a start.

Answer (score 0):

Parent component can communication with child component with parent props that have function in it. You can see code below `onFinished` property in Parent component has  `handleFinished()` function value in it. That fucntion will be a bridge to help Child component to communicate with Parent component. On the Child component you must run `onFinished` props to triggering `handleFinished` function on Parent comoponent. In code below the trigger for props.onFinished is when `<span>` clicked by user.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Grid } from "react-flexbox-grid";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { data: "test" };
  }

  render() {
    const items = ["red", "green", "blue"];
    const handleFinished = (e, index) => {
      this.setState({ data: e });
      console.log(this.state);
    };
    return (
      <Grid>
        {items.map((el, index) => (
          <Child
            prop1={"test"}
            prop2={"test1"}
            el={el}
            onFinished={(e) => handleFinished(e, index)}
          />
        ))}

        <div>{this.state.data.toString()}</div>
      </Grid>
    );
  }
}

const Child = (props) => {
  // example for your finishedClass value state
  const finishedClass = true;

  return (
    <span
      onClick={() => props.onFinished(finishedClass)}
      className={finishedClass ? "finishedItem" : ""}
    >
      {props.el}{" "}
    </span>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Answer (score -1):

As finishedClass is a state variable, if you just console.log(finishedClass) inside  component it will just do the work